# What is the difference between \vskip and \vspace?

Tags: macros, spacing

I found myself writing:

```
\vspace 1 \baselineskip
```

and then when it's not compiling changing without thinking to:

```
\vskip 1 \baselineskip
```

but what is the difference? Perhaps knowing this will make me write the right one from the start in the future...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015455/vspace-vs-vskip

Comment: oh that's why I didn't find it. That one is on stackoverflow I only searched this site...

Comment: @thiton: It is not possible to close a question as a duplicate of a question on a different stackexchange site.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I've flagged the SO question to be moved here, once that is done this question could be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vspace vs. vskip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30062/vspace-vs-vskip)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The syntax

```
\vspace 1\baselineskip
```

is incorrect, as `\vspace` (or, more precisely, the internal version `\@vspace`) is a command that takes one argument, so this would be equivalent to

```
\vspace{1}\baselineskip
```

which raises an error. However, also the two calls

```
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\vskip 1\baselineskip
```

are not equivalent. The former will not force end-of-paragraph, if given in LR-mode (using LaTeX parlance; horizontal mode in TeX parlance), adding the stated vertical spacing under the line in which it appears in the typeset document. With `\vskip`, which is a primitive TeX command, the current paragraph will be terminated.

With `\vspace` you have also the *-version, providing a vertical space that won't disappear at a page break; spacing inserted with `\vskip` will *always* disappear at a page break.

In general it's best to issue `\vspace` between paragraphs, but the "in-paragraph" feature may come up handy in some cases.

Lastly,

```
\vskip 1\baselineskip
Plus one
```

will give some surprises to those who are not accustomed with Plain TeX lingo.

*Note for the curious*: `\vglue 1\baselineskip` ends the paragraph and produces spacing that won't disappear at a page break. It's not documented in the LaTeX manuals, and it's good it isn't.

Comment: Why is it good it isn't? You piqued my curiosity...

Comment: @jonalv The main problem is the "foreign" syntax. If you write `\vglue{2\baselineskip}` you'll get an error. And `\vglue 2pt Minuscule beasts ...` will puzzle you.

Comment: That's why you always want to close assignments to numbers and dimensions with `\relax`, i suppose?

Comment: @Lupino Yes, which is done by `\vspace`.

Answer (score 18):

I’ve noticed this question because it popped up at the top of the list of active questions a few hours ago, and I would like to add another, minor remark to the excellent answer given by @egreg.

There is another difference between

```
\vskip \medskipamount % say
```

and

```
\vspace{\medskipamount}
```

and it is how they behave if an `\addvspace` and/or an `\addpenalty` command immediately follows them.  Indeed, `\vspace` adds a *second* zero-length skip, which causes an ensuing `\addvspace` (resp., `\addpenalty`) command *not* to remove the preceding space before adding its own vertical space (resp., penalty).  This zero-length skip is, of course, not added by `\vskip`, which is a primitive command, with the effect that an `\addvspace` that comes immediately after (that is, without intervening items in the current vertical list) will remove the vertical space added by `\vskip` if it shorter than the space specified in its own argument.

In other words, if you say

```
\vspace{\medskipamount}
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
```

*both* spaces will survive and you'll get a total vertical space of `\medskipamount`+`\bigskipamount`, whilst with

```
\vskip \medskipamount
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
```

only the taller of the two spaces will survive (`\bigskipamount`, in this case).

The behavior of `\addpenalty` is similar, but in order to see it clearly we need to look at the tracing produced by `\showlists`.  Consider the following (almost) MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10

\begin{document}

Short paragraph~\#1.

\vskip \medskipamount
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}

Short paragraph~\#~2.

\vspace{\medskipamount}
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}

Short paragraph~\#~3.

Let's now consider penalties.  To see the difference, you'll have to look at 
the transcript file, and read the tracing produced by \verb|\showlists|.

Short paragraph~\#4.

\vskip \medskipamount
\addpenalty{123}
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}

Short paragraph~\#~5.

\vspace{\medskipamount}
\addpenalty{123}
\addvspace{\bigskipamount}

Short paragraph~\#~6.

\showlists

\end{document}
```

This is the excerpt of the tracing that pertains to the tract between the “Short paragraphs” #4 and #5:

```
\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
\glue -7.94397 plus -2.0 minus -2.0
\penalty 123
\glue 1.94397
\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
\glue -6.0 plus -2.0 minus -2.0
\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
```

As you see, there is a backspace of `-7.94397 plus -2.0 minus -2.0` (points) before the penalty item: this backspace compensate both for the preceding vertical space of `6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0` (always points), that comes from `\vskip \medskipamount`, and for the depth of the last line of text (the latter being a recent correction of an old LaTeX bug).  Note also the second backspace before `\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0`, which is the glue corresponding to `\bigskipamount`.

On the other hand, the corresponding excerpt for paragraphs #5 and #6 is

```
\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
\glue 0.0
\penalty 123
\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
```

Here you can see the zero-length vertical space of which we spoke above, and no backspacing at all.

Answer (score 9):

And here is another difference. `\vskip` generates `\par` in horizontal mode (in order to terminate it) but `\vspace` behaves as `\vadjust{\vskip...}`. The result is: `\vskip` has very understandable behaviour but `\vspace` is a source of many confusions. You can verify this by inspecting this forum about users confusions about `\vspace` and misunderstanding of horizontal/vertical mode in TeX.

Comment: Note that @egreg’s answer already mentions this.  **Edit:** +1 for explicitly mentioning `\vadjust`, however. :-)