# \vspace vs. \vskip

Tags: macros, spacing, tex-core

What is the difference between `\vspace{-1em}` and `\vskip -1em`, for example? I guess the first is LaTeX, and the latter is TeX. When is the proper time to use one and not the other, and why?

Comment: I voted to close this question because @egreg has provided a canonical answer for the "question originally asked at tex.sx".

Comment: Okay, but this question was asked first.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

At any point in its processing, TeX is in some mode. There are six modes, divided in three
categories:

1. horizontal mode and restricted horizontal mode,
2. vertical mode and internal vertical mode, and
3. math mode and display math mode.

When not typesetting mathematics, TeX is in horizontal or vertical mode.
Horizontal mode is typically used to make lines of text; 
vertical mode is typically used to stack the lines of a paragraph on top of each other.

`\vskip` inserts a glue in a vertical list of the lines. Therefore `\vskip` breaks the horizontal mode and goes to the vertical mode.

`\vspace` can work in horizontal mode and vertical mode.
In horizontal mode `\vspace 1mm` is equivalent to `\vadjust{\vskip 1mm \vskip 0pt}` and inserts a space after the current line.
In vertical mode `\vspace 1mm` is equivalent to `\vskip 1mm \vskip 0pt`

`\vskip 0pt` is needed so `\removelastskip` can not remove your vertical space.

Full definition:

```
\vspace : -> \@ifstar \@vspacer \@vspace
```

Without `*` case (`\vspace 1mm`):

```
\@vspace: #1->\ifvmode \vskip #1 \vskip \z@skip \else \@bsphack \vadjust {\@restore
par \vskip #1 \vskip \z@skip }\@esphack \fi
```

Note `\z@skip` equal to `0pt`, `\@bsphack` is needed to save big horizontal space after period.
`\@esphack` is needed to return big space settings.

With `*` case (`\vspace* 1mm`):

```
\@vspacer:#1->\ifvmode \dimen@ \prevdepth \hrule \@height \z@ \nobreak \vskip #1 \v
skip \z@skip \prevdepth \dimen@ \else \@bsphack \vadjust {\@restorepar \hrule     @height \z@ \nobreak \vskip #1 \vskip \z@skip }\@esphack \fi
```

Comment: So if they are used outside of a paragraph (that is, in vertical mode), then the output would be exactly the same?

Answer (score 60):

`\vspace` is a LaTeX command and `\vskip` is a TeX command. Both can be used in LaTeX. 
When `\vspace` is used within a paragraph, it inserts space after the current line. But if `\vskip` is used within a paragraph it ends the paragraph and inserts the space immediately.

Comment: Why does `\vskip` start a new line? Is this a side effect of what Charles refers to as "vertical mode?"

Comment: @Geoff: `\vskip` start a new line by design. `vskip` is a vertical skip. Donald Knuth decided so.

Answer (score 40):

The difference by example :

```
\documentclass[preview, border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \textcolor{red}{Line with \texttt{vspace} :} \vspace{1cm} \blindtext

    \hrulefill

    \textcolor{red}{Line with \texttt{vskip} :} \vskip 1cm \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Exactly as Rob says; to rephrase, `\vskip` should be used when you are in, or want to start setting in, vertical mode, and `\vspace` makes sense within a paragraph.

The (an?) implementation of `\vspace` is discussed in [Eijkhout 1990, TUGboat 11(4), p618](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb11-4/tb30eijkhout-parskip.pdf).