# Space between images

Tags: line-breaking

I use `\\` for line breaks like the followings. I am wondering if there are better ways to do rather than adding `\\`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Find the unknown values and in each case, give a reason. 

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image1.png}
\\
\\
\\
\\
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image2.png}
\\
\\
\\
\\
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image3.png}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

My second day of LaTeX, yeah.

Comment: Please **complete** your code to make it compile. This requires at least adding `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` etc. You can use images from the `mwe` package such as `example-image-a`. What is the spacing designed to do? If say, you want to leave precisely 4 lines worth of space for people to write in, it might be OK. If you are adding those to e.g. fill the page, there are better ways of doing it such as `\vfill`. If you just want a largish gap, `\bigskip` might work. Without knowing the effect you want, it is hard to say.

Comment: Generally, a minimum working example is helpful, which includes everything needed to compile, nothing extra.  Remove packages that have nothing to do with the issue, as well as extraneous text.  This is super helpful in building a solution that addresses you exact needs.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to use `\\ ` outside of an alignment environment such as `tabular`. Certainly never use multiple `\\ ` or end a paragraph with `\\ `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to what cslstr says regarding the use of `\\` :). Hwoever, you can use package `enumitem` and adjust the distances between items as below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1in]
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image1.png}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image2.png}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image3.png}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not good practice to use multiple `\\` to insert extra space.  It happens to work here, but often you will get a `No line to end here` error from LaTeX.  `\vspace` is usually a good way to do what you like.  `\vfill` and `\bigskip` are other vertical spacing commands that might help.  The differences between some of these depends on the mode that LaTeX is in at any one point; see [\vspace vs. \vskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30062/vspace-vs-vskip), for example.

That said, you can use `\vspace` in this case to control things more precisely:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image1.png}
\vspace{1in}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image2.png}
\vspace{2in}
    \item
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6,valign=t]{images/image3.png}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This will give you:

[image: pic of spacing between images]