# Why does vspace add vertical space after the first line of a paragraph?

Tags: vertical-alignment, indentation, overleaf

I have defined a custom text font command using :

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\desc}{
    \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}
    \fontseries{light}\selectfont
    \vspace{10px}
}
```

And I have used it like that :

```
\desc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at tempor ex. Praesent a luctus enim. Nam mauris odio, ornare at egestas ut, mollis aliquet est. Nunc a rutrum tortor. Suspendisse et odio rutrum, porta ipsum non, fermentum turpis.}
```

I expected to have a 10 px space after the paragraph, but the space is added after the first line :

[image: Space is added after the first line of the paragrpah]

Also, why are the second and third lines are not aligned with the first line since I removed the indent of the paragraph? Those are shifted left in the margin of the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show *how* you are using the macro. But I guess you are calling your macro in a paragraph (aka "horizontal mode") where the LaTeX macro `\vspace` expands to the TeX primitive `\vadjust`, which does what you see. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30065/82917. Oh, and the indentation is likely the product of spurious spaces in your definition. But again, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue.

Comment: The identation problem was because of spaces, like you said. Adding empty comments after each line fixed it.

Comment: 11pt on 11pt is very tight (often unachievable) spacing, do you intend it to be that tightly spaced?

Answer (score 2):

`\vspace` adds the space at the point where it's called. So, for example if you write

```
Foo

\vspace{1in} 
Foo
```

The space goes betwen paragraphs, while

```
Foo
\vspace{1in}    
Foo
```

puts it after the line on which the first `Foo` appears. So surely, we should see, if we have

```
Foo

\desc{Foo}
```

that the space comes between the paragraphs, right? Except that you're using `\DeclareTextFontCommand` which does a little bit more. In particular, it does:

```
\def \DeclareTextFontCommand #1#2{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1[1]{%
    \ifmmode
      \nfss@text{#2##1}%
    \else
      \hmode@bgroup % ❶
       \text@command{##1}%
       #2\check@icl ##1\check@icr
       \expandafter
\egroup \fi
}
```

❶ is the critical line here. `\hmode@bgroup` leaves vertical mode (so it begins the paragraph) and then begins a group. So your `\vspace` is being output *after* the paragraph begins and comes after the first line.

Most likely, what you want is not to use `\DeclareTextFontCommand` at all. Assuming that you want to use this as a marker at the beginning of paragraphs, you could instead do:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ m }{%
   \par
   \vspace{10px}
   {%
      \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}%
      \fontseries{light}\selectfont
      #1
   }%   
}
```

to get your desired effect.

(Side note, I'd not seen `px` as a unit in TeX before. It's apparently equivalent to `bp` or the PostScript point of 1/72 in. It's not mentioned in *The TeXbook* as far as I know. Apparently an eTeX enhancement as it's an illegal unit if I use `tex` but is available with `pdftex` and any of the LaTeX engines which all *require* eTeX.)

Comment: px came from pdftex (rather than pure etex) but etex these days is pdftex in dvi mode so it comes to the same thing:-)

Answer (score 0):

Environments are easier to use and and fixed my problem. The second {} contains the styles to apply before the text and the third {} contains the styles to apply after the text.

```
\newenvironment{desc}{%
    \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}%
    \fontseries{light}\selectfont%
    \begin{spacing}{1.1}%
}{\end{spacing}\vspace{10px}}
```

Adding % after each line fixed my second problem. Without these, whitespace would shift the text right.