# ToC page numbers for chapter*{} and chapter{} are not aligned

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, page-numbering

I am trying to write my master thesis in PDFLaTeX using texmaker and being complete novice to LaTeX I probably overcomplicated my solution and it's not giving me what I want.

Problem I am facing: Wstęp (Introduction) page number (generated with  in Table of Contents is not aligned with other page numbers in Table of Contents.
[image: ToC problem image]

Preferred solution: ToC page numbers to be all aligned (in 1 "column")

I would gladly accept any help with how to fix my code :) Thank you in advance!

Full code that I am using to generate document in TexMaker below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
% Are there any coding standards to adhere to?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % centering etc
\usepackage{charter} % [T1]{fontenc} {charter} allow to search words in pd
\usepackage[polish]{babel}  %setting up polish language
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry} % page margins set-up

% Packages for specific font sizes
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times New Roman font
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%Font Specifications
\ifdefined\directlua
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries\selectfont}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries\selectfont}
% Package to add dots in ToC
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
 [0pt]% <left>
 {\vspace{0,5cm}}% <above-code>
 {\bfseries\MakeUppercase\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
 {}% <numberless-entry-format>
 {\space\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage} %<filler-page-format>
 {}
%
%\dotfill\contentspage\vspace{0,5cm}

\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
 [0pt]% <left>
 {\vspace{0,5cm}}% <above-code>
 {\bfseries\MakeUppercase\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
 {}% <numberless-entry-format>
 {\space\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage} %<filler-page-format>
 {}

% Table of contents depth setting - to including subsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\dotfill}{%
  \leavevmode\cleaders\hbox to 0.7em{\hss .\hss }\hfill\kern0pt }
% \thecontentslabel

% Font sizes
% redefine pagestyle headings because in xetex, left and right in
% the headers are swapped.
% Redefining section to have adjusted font sizes
% setting chapter font size at 12
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}}


%starting sections redefining parameters
% The arguments of \@startsection are:
%    #1 name of the heading level (relevant for labels and references)
%    #2 heading level (relevant for secnumdepth and tocdepth counters)
%    #3 indent (\z@ is 0pt)
%    #4 space before: when less than 0pt, no parindent is inserted after the heading, if greater or equal to 0pt, parindent is inserted. \@plus and \@minus add positive and negative glue, i.e., room for TeX to stretch or shrink vertical space(s) to fill the page down to the bottom
% #5 space after: values <0pt make inline headings with the amount as horizontal space, positive values make vertical space. Can also have glue.
% #6 are font switches like font family, font size, font weight, etc.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   %defining font size of series %\normalsize
                                   {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont\bfseries}} 
                                                                  
                                   
% defining chapter function
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    % defining chapter font
    % adding \centering for center display and \MakeUppercase for upper case
        \chapfnt\bfseries\centering\MakeUppercase \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
   % adding \centering for center display and \MakeUppercase for upper case
    \chapfnt \bfseries\centering\MakeUppercase #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

  
  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section*{\centerline{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
    \@mkboth
      {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
      {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
  }%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}

\makeatother
\makeatletter

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % allowing hyperlinks 
% Standard parameters
\author{Testeur TheTester}
\title{While testing this test became super test}

% New parameters
% Cannot have special characters in names - keep to lowercase and only characters
\newcommand\doccreator{Testeur TheTester}
\newcommand\doctitle{What is love - baby don't hurt me}
\newcommand\school{University of Mammon}
\newcommand\department{FIAT Department}
\newcommand\id{5517}
\newcommand\engtitle{Optimal Portfolio Allocation}
\newcommand\faculty{Shadow Economy}
\newcommand\thesistype{magisterska}
\newcommand\supervisora{dr Very Noble}
\newcommand\supervisorb{from Notre Dame Cathedral}
\newcommand\supervisorc{WNE UW}
\newcommand{\vertspace}{\vskip 1mm}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30062/vspace-vs-vskip

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{2in}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.5}


%Parametry dokumentu
\label{foo}
\begin{titlepage}%
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \begin{center}%
  
{\fontsize{18pt}{21.6pt}\selectfont} 
  {\Huge \school\\ \department\par}
      \vspace{2cm}
 {\fontsize{14pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
 {\Large \doccreator \par}
       {\large ID: \id\par}
      \vspace{2cm}
{\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont} 
       {\Huge\textbf{\doctitle}\par}
    
      \vspace{1cm plus 1fill} 

      {\large\ Praca \thesistype \\
        na kierunku: \faculty } \\
      \vspace{2cm plus 2fill}
      \end{center}
            \vspace{1cm plus 1.5fill}
      \begin{flushright}

          Praca wykonana pod kierunkiem\\
           \supervisora \\
                          \supervisorb \\
                          \supervisorc

      \end{flushright}
      \vspace{1cm plus 0.8fill}
      % miesiąc i~rok:
      \begin{center}
      Lipiec 2023
      \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
% starting numbering from 2nd page
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
   \textit{Oświadczenia kierującego pracą }
      \vspace{10mm}
\begin{justify} 
Oświadczam, że niniejsza praca została przygotowana pod moim kierunkiem i stwierdzam, że spełnia ona warunki do przedstawienia jej w postępowaniu o nadanie tytułu zawodowego.
\end{justify}
    \vspace{15mm}   
   Data \hfill Podpis kierującego pracą
   \vspace{3cm} \\
   \textit{Oświadczenie autora pracy}
    \vspace{10mm}
\begin{justify}
Świadom odpowiedzialności prawnej oświadczam, że niniejsza praca dyplomowa została napisana przeze mnie samodzielnie i nie zawiera treści uzyskanych w sposób niezgodny z obowiązującymi przepisami.
\end{justify}
     \vspace{10mm}
\begin{justify}
Oświadczam również, że przedstawiona praca nie była wcześniej przedmiotem procedur związanych z uzyskaniem tytułu zawodowego w wyższej uczelni.
\end{justify}
\vertspace
\begin{justify}
Oświadczam ponadto, że niniejsza wersja pracy jest identyczna z załączoną wersją elektroniczną.
\end{justify}
   \vspace{15mm}   
   Data \hfill Podpis autora pracy
\newpage
  \vspace*{26pt}%
  \begin{center}%
    \textbf{Streszczenie} \\
    Kiedy Kamil, kiedy Kamil był prezesem NBP hej
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{26pt}%
  \begin{center}%
    \textbf{Słowa kluczowe} \\
    \#ŻYĆKO \#WYGRANKO \#MAGISTERKO
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{26pt}%
  \begin{center}%
    \textbf{Dziedzina pracy (kody wg programu Socrates-Erasmus)} \\
    11.4 Sztuczna inteligencja
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{26pt}%
  \begin{center}%
    \textbf{Klasyfikacja tematyczna} \\
    D. Software\\
    D.127. Blabalgorithms\\
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{26pt}%
  \begin{center}%
    \textbf{Tytuł pracy w języku angielskim} \\
    While this was developed something other entirely was created
  \end{center}
  \nobreak\vfil\null

\newpage    
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter*{WSTĘP}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{WSTĘP}}
%\quad\protect
\addtocontents{toc}{\linebreak[1]}
\chapter{Who invented rap?}
\section{Historical Overview}
\chapter{Implementation}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}
\subsection{Why and what - but especially where}


\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you say `\titleformat{\section}` a few times and the do `\renewcommand{\section}`. Similarly, you have `\titleformat{\chapter}` and then redefine `\@makechapterhead`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\titlecontents{chapter*}% <section-type>
```

instead of

```
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
```

and delete

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\linebreak[1]}%
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much :)