# Creating a title page using \vspace or \vskip

Tags: macros, spacing, titles

I'm creating a title page and I'm asking if it's more convenient to use `\vspace` or `\vskip` to have distance between title, author and other elements in the page.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30062/vspace-vs-vskip  might help you

Comment: I read it but it didn't understand well the difference in using it

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/what-is-the-difference-between-vskip-and-vspace

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\vspace` is essentially a LaTeX wrapper around the primitive `\vskip`, but it sports a few differences.

1. `\vspace` doesn't end a paragraph, while `\vskip` does;
2. `\vspace` has the *-variant, which `\vskip` doesn't;
3. `\vspace` protects the user from possible ambiguous input (see [What is the difference between \vskip and \vspace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/what-is-the-difference-between-vskip-and-vspace) for an example).

So the answer is: use `\vspace`, but always precede it with a blank line (or a `\par` command) when you want to separate with vertical spaces two objects.

Note that `\vspace*` should be used at the top, otherwise this space would vanish at the page break (and even the first page is considered to come after a page break: computer scientists always start counting from 0).

Answer (score 2):

This might be tricky. I would say: use whichever you feel comfortable with. Just some recommendations:

- The whole title should be robust against paper size changes and margin changes.
- This can be done by enclosing it in something like `\leavevmode\vfill...\vfill\leavevmode` which centers `...` vertically on the page.
- For the distances, you can use `\vspace{3cm minus 1cm}` to make the vertical space shrinkable in the case the title is several lines long for instance and your titlepage would not fit on one page because of that. The `minus 1cm` part says, how much can be shrinked (removed) from the vertical space if necessary.