# Glue at the top of the page is ignored

Tags: spacing

I wonder why adding vertical glue at the very top a page has no effect.

E.g. the following code produces a 2 inch vertical space before the second paragraph, but no space whatsoever before the first one.

```
\begin{document}

\vskip2in
First paragraph.

\vskip2in
Second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33372/586 See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/creating-a-title-page-using-vspace-or-vskip/50444#50444

Comment: Note I removed the [tag:plain-tex] tag as the solution here (use `\vspace*`) is not applicable to plain TeX