# How to start half way down a page or skip some whitespace in a page?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking

In latex, one can use the command `\newpage` to skip to a new page.

Is there a similar method of skipping to the next half way point in a page? (Whether this be halfway down the current page or just create a new page.)

To explain this more fully, I am writing an "Acknowledgements" page. This is appended at the end of my document, so I have used `\newpage` to start a new page for the Acknowledgements section.

I have put a few lines in there thanking various people, so have used about a quarter of a page.

I now wish to start half-way down the page and add an "in memory of" note.

How can I do this?

One possible method may be to insert a list of newlines?

```
Thanks to ...
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
In memory of ...
```

But I'm hoping there is a better way to skip several lines?

Comment: `\vspace{0.5\textheight}` perhaps?

Comment: `\vspace{15cm}` or whatever you want as a distance should work after you have already text on the top of the page.

Comment: much better than using a string of `\\ ` is to skip a blank line after the text, then insert `\vspace*{n\baselineskip}`, where `n` is the number of lines you want to leave blank.  the `*` will guarantee that the space is not ignored at the top of a page.  (probably not necessary here, but useful to know.)

Answer (score 6):

I would accomplish this by combining Christian Hupfer's suggestion of `\vspace{0.5\textheight}` with a `\vfill`.

First I would have the few lines thanking various people, then a `\vfill`, then `In (loving) memory of` then `\vspace{0.5\textheight}`.

The `\vspace{0.5\textheight}` guarantees that underneath `In (loving) memory of` there is a space of half the height of the page. I then have a `\vfill` between the two portions of text. The first portion of text is at the top. The `\vfill` is a rubber length, which will expand to take up all the available vertical space, pushing `In (loving) memory of` to the line precisely above the halfway point.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vfill
In (loving) memory of
\vspace{0.5\textheight}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I assume you wanted a string of `\\`'s? You're right that you should never drop multiple lines like this. In fact, I get a

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

error, surely you do as well? A series of hard broken lines with invisible content, however, is still not the way to go.

Comment: I wanted a short paragraph at the bottom of my title page without it being a footnote. `\vfill` and nothing under the paragraph but a `\pagebreak` did just what I wanted, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

As showed in comments and previous answer, for vertical spacing you can use `\vspace`, `\vskip`, `\vfill` or `\vfil` or their combinations. Only add that the first two are not exactly the same (see [What is the difference between \vskip and \vspace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/what-is-the-difference-between-vskip-and-vspace)) and well as the later two, but  `\vspace` or `\vskip` could be also rubber lengths (e.g `\vskip 10em plus 1em minus .2em`) allowing a lot of flexibility.

However, to legitimate this as a valid answer, here are a very different approach: In any case, with the above solutions, minor changes in the text extensions could change the position of the "In memoriam". Whereas this is the generally expected/desired effect, may be you want maintain their position irrespectively of text changes above or below. One way to fix an absolute position is the `texpos` package. Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article} 
\usepackage[lmargin=24mm,rmargin=24mm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid{148}{210} 
\begin{document}
\section*{Thanks to ...}\lipsum[2]
\begin{textblock}{100}(24,105)
\section*{In memory of...} \lipsum[3]
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is interesting, good solution :) Out of genuine interest, what sort of changes would cause a change in the position of "In memory of" in my solution? Obviously if the text before it is too long and would take up the top half of the page, there'd be no room for "In memory of"; but that would prevent it from appearing halfway down the page in any solution

Comment: @Au101 Because the `[absolute]` option,  the `texblock` environment always stay at the same position, but may change of page if the the previous text fill the page. Keep in mind that  `texblock` does not take space,  so another  side effect is that text before/after may overlap (e.g.: change `\lipsum[2]` by `\lipsum[2-3]`) .  The good news are that you can use relative positions (e.g.  (remove `[absolute]` and use`\begin{textblock}{100}(0,2)`) and/or make room for the `textblock` (e.g. change `\lipsum[2]` by `\lipsum[2]\vfill Some text`).

Answer (score 1):

`\vspace` or `\vspace*` should do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
Foo
\vspace*{0.5\textheight}

In (loving) memory of 
\end{document}
```

[image]