# How to change interline spacing only inside lists?

Tags: spacing, lists, line-spacing, enumitem, setspace

If I do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setstretch{2}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=.1em,itemsep=.1em,parsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\setlist*[itemize]{first=\setstretch{1}}    % This undesirably affects the spacing before the list

\begin{document}

\def\text{test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph}

\text

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

\text

\end{document}
```

Then I get:

[image: bad spacing between list and previous paragraph]

But that is not what I want. I want to keep the spacing just before the list unchanged, but change only the spacing between lines of the list. Is there any way I can automatically achieve this for all itemize/enumerate lists, regardless of the interline-spacing of their surrounding text?

Comment: Coukd you please post a small, yet complete, example code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `first=\par\setstretch` causes a compile error...

Comment: use `\setlist*[itemize]{first=\singlespacing}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Why do we need `\endgraf` instead of `\par`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: What if I want something else like `\setstretch{1.3}`? Anyway how does `\singlespacing` work? Its internal mechanism might give an answer to my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Um, it doesn't work at all (made it worse); did `\endgraf` actually work for you?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok sure; I just wanted to make sure it wasn't somehow my fault for it not working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's why I initially asked in a comment on the other thread, because using `first` instead of `before` solves the problem of affecting the entire previous paragraph (when there is no empty line before the start of the list, not here), but doesn't solve the space in-between that and the list.

Comment: ah `before` and `\endgraf` then:-), incidentally do you _really_ want setstretch{2} it is so spacy to be hardly readable, and way more than "doublespaced" (eg the `setspace` package uses `\setstretch {1.667}` for `\doublespace`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No, as you all requested, this is just a toy example. I simply want an automated solution that would work with any choice of interline-spacing in the surrounding environments and any choice of spacing inside the lists. After looking at the definition of `\singlespacing`, I think I have a solution, so I'm going to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a commenter suggested `\singlespacing`, I looked at its definition and I think the following works in all cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setstretch{2}
\setlist[itemize,enumerate]{topsep=.1em,itemsep=.1em,parsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\setlist*[itemize,enumerate]{first=\vskip\baselineskip\setstretch{1.1}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\def\text{test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph}

\text

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \end{enumerate}
\item four
\end{itemize}

\text

\end{document}
```

The `1.1` can obviously be changed arbitrarily. It produces:

[image: proper spacing before list]

Answer (score 4):

On way is simply to adjust for the changed baseline:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setstretch{2}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=.1em,itemsep=.1em,parsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\setlist*[itemize]{first=\vspace{\baselineskip}\setstretch{1}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}    % This undesirably affects the spacing before the list

\begin{document}

\def\text{test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph}

\text

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

\text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see your answer while I was typing mine. Comparing, is there a benefit to using `\vspace` instead of `\vskip` for the first spacing?

Comment: @user21820 `\vspace` is latex, `\vskip` is a tex primitive so not really at the same level as an enumitem keyval setting (but does same thing)

Comment: Hmm, I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30052) which claimed a whole bunch of differences, so I wasn't sure. It *seems* like my choice of `\vskip` may be better aligned with the notion of changing line-spacing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user21820 I am sure

Comment: Lol so it yields identical results in all cases? Why? Can you briefly explain why "*The former will not force end-of-paragraph*" from the linked post does not apply here?

Comment: @user21820 the list code has already started vertical mode

Comment: Ahh okay I get it, sorry I forgot about that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about this, using the `before` and `after` keys?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setstretch{2}
    \setlist[itemize]{topsep=.1em, itemsep=.1em,parsep=0em, partopsep=0em}
    \setlist[itemize]{before=\begin{singlespace}, after=\end{singlespace}}

    \begin{document}

    \def\text{test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph test paragraph}

    \text

    \begin{itemize}
    \item one\text
    \item two
    \item three
    \end{itemize}

    \text

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, this fails to address my question; I said "*regardless of the interline-spacing of their surrounding text*". So your proposal fails in many many situations, including but not restricted to nested lists.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no obvious solution about the spacing of the list w.r.t. the surrounding text. Maybe some guru (which I'm not) will find something…

Comment: See my answer. Yours isn't an answer at all (see the nested lists in mine), and I think you should delete it.

Comment: Your last edit (after my previous comments) does make your post an answer to my question (and works with nested lists), but is not general at all. It also fails in some special cases (e.g. if there is no empty line before the `\begin{itemize}`), which is the reason the `first` key is correct and your choice of `before` key is wrong. So clearly there is something very wrong with the voters on TeX SE.