# Expex \vskip before example does not disappear at a page break

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking, vertical-spacing, expex, vskip

I have a `book` document with `\flushbottom`. I use [expex](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex) for linguistic examples. When an example is the first item on a page, the previous page ends with some spurious whitespace, as can be seen in the MWE below.

`\ex` (which starts an example) inserts `\exbreak`, which is defined as:

```
\def\exbreak{\endgraf\bgroup\@getoptionalarg\exbreak@a}
\def\exbreak@a{%
   \ifx\@optionalarg\empty
         \skip255=\lingexbreakfil
      \else
         \skip255= 0pt plus\@optionalarg
      \fi
   \vskip\skip255
   \penalty\lingexbreakpenalty
   \vskip-\skip255
   \egroup
}
```

(By default, `\lingexbreakfil=0pt plus 4ex` and `\lingexbreakpenalty=-50` (contra the documentation).)

The behaviour of `\exbreak` is explained as follows in the documentation:

> It not only ends the current paragraph and awards a penalty
> (a reward if the penalty is negative) if a page break is taken at that point, but makes it easier for a
> satisfactory page break to be taken by allowing the page to end with some vertical fill, allowing
> some whitespace to appear at the bottom of the broken page.

I can get the desired `\flushbottom` effect by removing the `\vskip\skip255`. I am not sure what the purpose of the negative `\vskip` after the penalty is. This means I can also get the desired effect using `\lingset{exbreakfil=0pt}`.

What I do not understand is why this happens. According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30052), "spacing inserted with `\vskip` will *always* disappear at a page break". So why does the space inserted by the first `\vskip` not disappear here?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=4cm,top=6cm,bottom=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext[4][1]

\ex
\begingl
\glpreamble A rather long example //
\gla with glosses //
\glb explaining the //
\glc meaning of //
\glft `the text' //
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

Comment: vskip *after* the break (and so at the begin of the begin of the page) disappears (that's why you don't go up on the second page as the negative vskip has not effect).  The negative vskip is needed in case you are in the middle of the page: if there is not break between both it negates the effect of the positive vskip.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I'd say that qualifies as an answer!